# ASP MVC3 DropDownListFor with blank default option

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm populating a small set of drop down list items in my model list so:

```
    SecSellerCodes = (from s in db.DropDownValues
                        where s.Field.Equals("SecSellerCd") &&
                            s.DisplayPage.Equals("Agent Create")
                        select s).Select(x => new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = x.DisplayValue,
                                Value = x.AllowedValue
                            }).Distinct().ToList();
```

I would like the user to be able to select from the list of items pulled from the query above, plus include a blank option at the top of the list in case they do not want this particular field populated.

Using the following helper, this works fine once the page loads/user saves to the database. However, if they need to reload the page and make adjustments, the blank `string.Empty` item is always selected (no matter the value in the table).

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SecSellerCd, Model.SecSellerCodes, string.Empty)
```

Any idea which helper/technique to use to accomplish this?

Comment: If the value of property `SecSellerCd` matchs one of the values in the `SelectList`, (i.e. `x.AllowedValue`) then it will be selected. Are you sure there are matching values

Comment: Yes. In this case the Display and Allowed values are the same. I've verified that a valid value is present in the field.

Comment: Strange. Try creating `SecSellerCodes` as a `SelectList` - `var values = (from s in db.DropDownValues where ... select s); SecSellerCodes = new SelectList(values, "AllowedValue", "DisplayValue");`

Comment: So it looks like there's an extra space being placed at the end of each value when it's saved to the database. Not sure how that's happening but that is what's throwing the program off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model code you need to assign the selected value to model.SecSellerCd. So if you want them to make changes from previous selection then you need to save the selected value in the database as well.